# How a bootstrap template integrate with an existing project working with webpack?

Tags: webpack, bootstrapping, webpack-dev-server

I got a existing project using webpack to build. 
And I find that the SB Admin 2 is fit for my development:
https://github.com/blackrockdigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/

So, I would like to get use of this template. Instead of copy and paste the CSS, js to my own project. Is this possible to integrate with webpack? Please advise.

Comment: i have the some probleme , ur u find the way ?